# Is it possible to create a custom hook event in Subversion

Tags: svn, hook, svn-hooks

I am new to subversion administration. Is it possible to create a custom event in subversion for firing a hook, for example I want a script to be executed at repository creation. Is it possible for me to create a hook that will be executed when a new repository is created.

Also can anyone of you please explain how subversion hook is fired. For example,how a pre-commit hook is fired. How subversion knows that before each commit a particular script should be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

You know that a hook is executed on the Subversion server side not on client side. So this means that based on the creation of a repository it's simply impossible, cause the hook script is part of the repository. So in this case it's not possible.

The basics are based on the script which are located in the hooks folder of the repository. If these scripts are defined to be executable (+ name) they will be executed otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, and as the names of the hooks clearly say so, when a user makes a commit to the Subversion server, the server runs the `pre-commit` hook before performing the commit, and then when commit is done successfully, the `post-commit` is run afterwards.

Regarding what should be executed is quite customisable. You can have simple shell scripts to run, that in turn would call other scripts (e.g. PHP, Python.. etc). It is up to you.

Simply edit the `post-commit` file in the `hooks` directory of the repository on the SERVER, and then every time a client commits, those scripts will run.

Check this for more info: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html, particularly the section titled 'Implementing Repository Hooks'